# API response is taking too long on React Native Expo's Android internal distribution build when using Mobile Data

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

While testing the app, I noticed that the API response time is significantly slow when I use mobile data. But, it is working as expected when I use Wi-Fi.

I've spent all week trying to figure out why. Navigation can take around 10000-30000 ms.

The app was implemented using React Native Expo, and I generated the APK using the following command:  `eas build --profile preview --platform android`

These are the observations we have noticed when we used Mobile Data.

- Some mobiles are taking longer time on the first HTTP request and after that working properly.
- Few mobiles are taking a longer time for all the HTTP requests.

** Note: There is no issue with Wi-Fi.

I have observed that the API calls are taking longer than expected, causing delays in data retrieval. I'm looking for suggestions or guidance on how to troubleshoot and improve the API response time that would be appreciated.

Comment: did you find a solution for this? I'm experiencing something similar